# Order menu produce [Object,object],[object,object] Firebase Ionic 3

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I have been figuring out how to solve this problems for days but I am still unable to produce the item list. Can anyone help? Thank you!

**typescript file**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';


import { orderItem } from './../../models/order';


@IonicPage()

@Component({
  selector: 'page-cashierorder',
  templateUrl: 'cashierorder.html',
})

export class CashierorderPage {

  orderItemRef$: FirebaseListObservable<any>

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
    private database: AngularFireDatabase,) {

    this.orderItemRef$ = this.database.list('orders');
  }


}
```

**HTML file**

```
<ion-content padding>
    <ion-list>

              <ion-item *ngFor="let item of orderItemRef$ | async">
                <h2>ORDER MENU: {{item.Ordermenu}}</h2>  
                <h2>ORDER NUMBER: {{item.orderNumber}}</h2>
                  <h3>ORDER TOTAL: {{item.orderTotal}}</h3>
                  <h4>ORDER STATUS: {{item.orderStatus}}</h4>
                    </ion-item>
                  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

However, others seem to work but not for ORDERMENU. Here is my result when I run it on ionic serve:

[image: Inside ionic serve]

My firebase:

[image: Firebase description]

Can anyone help me to produce the itemName and the itemPrice? Thanksss

Answer (score 0):

Ordermenu has an underlying structure which is why you can't print it directly like that. You have to go down further down your structure from Ordermenu and decide what you want to print

Comment: I am not sure about the coding on how to go further down into my structure, is there any way you can help me?

Comment: Try adding .value after the ordermenu